# Serialize encrypted password to XML

Tags: c++, xml, qt, encryption

I have an application that contains userbase which is stored in xml file and loaded at the start of the program. I use QXmlStreamWriter/Reader for this purpose. The problem occurs when I try to serialize encrypted (hashed?) form of password (using QCryptographicHash and Sha256 for this).

QCryptographicHash return QByteArray, which can be converted to QString (necessary for use of QXmlStreamWriter/Reader). Relevant code below. Everything works fine before the serialization (I can log in), but when I read data from xml, after finding hashed password the function behaves like it found the EOF, and only about 2 chars are loaded to the QString by QXmlStreamReader.

In the code please ignore reservations etc (it's a cinema panel), relevant fragments are passwords, I supply full function just in case.

I hope I explained what the issue is, here are fragments of my code (note: before adding the hashing everything worked fine)

Register function (the hashing, pass is a QString):

```
QString hash = QCryptographicHash::hash(pass.toUtf8(), QCryptographicHash::Sha256);

User* user_pointer;
user_pointer = new User(name, hash, admin);
```

Writing function:

```
QFile file("users/users.xml");
if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    throw "Error podczas otwierania bazy użytkowników!";


    QXmlStreamWriter writer (&file);

    writer.setAutoFormatting(true);
    writer.writeStartDocument();
    writer.writeStartElement("USERS");
    int list_size = userList.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < list_size; i++)
    {
        writer.writeStartElement("USER");
        writer.writeTextElement("name", userList.at(i)->name);
        writer.writeTextElement("pass", userList.at(i)->password);
        writer.writeTextElement("admin", QString::number(userList.at(i)->is_admin));
        writer.writeStartElement("RESERVATIONS");
        for(int m = 0; m < userList.at(i)->reservList.size(); m++)
        {
            writer.writeStartElement("reservation");
            writer.writeTextElement("moviename", userList.at(i)->reservList.at(m)->movie_name);
            writer.writeTextElement("date", userList.at(i)->reservList.at(m)->date.toString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
            writer.writeTextElement("hour", (userList.at(i)->reservList.at(m)->hour).toString("hhmm"));
            writer.writeTextElement("paid", QString::number(userList.at(i)->reservList.at(m)->paid));
            for(int n = 0; n < userList.at(i)->reservList.at(m)->placeList.size(); n++)
                writer.writeTextElement("place", QString::number(userList.at(i)->reservList.at(m)->placeList.at(n)));
            writer.writeEndElement();
        }
        writer.writeEndElement();
        writer.writeEndElement();
    }
    writer.writeEndDocument();


  file.close();

}
```

Reading function:

```
QFile file("users/users.xml");
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    throw "Brak bazy danych użytkowników lub błąd jej otworzenia!";

QXmlStreamReader reader;

reader.setDevice(&file);
reader.readNext();

QString user_name;
QString user_pass;
bool admin;
QString movie_name;
QTime hour;
QDate date;
bool paid;

User* user_pointer = NULL;
int user_counter = -1;
Reservation* reserv_pointer = NULL;
int reserv_counter = -1;

while(!reader.atEnd())
{
    if(reader.isStartElement())
    {
        if(reader.name() == "USER")
        {
            reserv_counter = -1;

        }

        if(reader.name() == "name")
            user_name = reader.readElementText();
        if(reader.name() == "pass")
            user_pass = reader.readElementText();
        if(reader.name() == "admin")
        {
            admin = reader.readElementText().toInt();
            user_pointer = new User(user_name, user_pass, admin);
            userList.append(user_pointer);

            user_counter++;
        }
        if(reader.name() == "reservation")
        {
            reserv_counter++;
        }
        if(reader.name() == "moviename")
            movie_name = reader.readElementText();
        if(reader.name() == "hour")
            hour = QTime::fromString(reader.readElementText(), "hhmm");
        if(reader.name() == "date")
            date = QDate::fromString(reader.readElementText(), "dd.MM.yyyy");
        if(reader.name() == "paid")
        {
            paid = reader.readElementText().toInt();
            reserv_pointer = new Reservation(movie_name, date, hour, paid);
            userList.at(user_counter)->reservList.append(reserv_pointer);
        }
        if(reader.name() == "place")
          {
            userList.at(user_counter)->reservList.at(reserv_counter)->placeList.append(reader.readElementText().toInt());

          }

        reader.readNextStartElement();
    }
    else
        reader.readNext();
}

file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash value is not a string, it is a sequence of arbitrary byte values, some of those might happen to be problematic when interpreting it as a string.

You have an implicit conversion from `QByteArray` to `QString`, for which the documentation says that:

> The byte array is converted to Unicode using the fromUtf8() function.
>   This function stops conversion at the first NUL character found, or
>   the end of the ba byte array.

You could for example use explicit conversion which specifies the length:

```
QString::fromUtf8(byteArray.data(), length);
```

As Frank Osterfeld noted in the comments, using UTF8 is not a good idea, I have tested from and to Latin1 extensively for a project I was working on, and the binary data is identical, however in looks "funky" in textual form, which may not play well with the XML reading and writing, `toHex()` will fix that by limiting the character set to 0-F:

```
QByteArray b; // hash
QString ss = QString::fromLatin1(b.toHex()); // to QString
b = QByteArray::fromHex(ss.toLatin1()); // back to QByteArray
```

Comment: That won't work if the binary data isn't valid utf-8, as it's probably the case here. I'd use QString::fromLatin1(byteArray.toHex()). Alternative to toHex() would be toBase64()

Comment: I haven't tested from/to for UTF8, it does appear to work OK with Latin1. I'd actually go for a binary format rather than XML to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that XML is a text format but encrypted passwords are a binary format. The two are not compatible. You need to have some way to encode the binary data in a text-friendly format.

As @ddriver has mentioned, one way to do this is to use `QByteArray::toHex()` since it will convert all bytes to human readable text characters. The cost, however, is a 100% increase in size (2 characters returned for each byte of the password hash)

Another, more ubiquitous, and efficient, method for transmitting binary data in textual form is to use the `QByteArray::toBase64()`. While it also returns binary data in a textual form, there's only a 33 1/3% increase in size (4 bytes returned for every 3 bytes of password hash).

(You might recognise this encoding since its the nonsensical text that usually ends with one or two `=` characters, and is the usual encoding used to transmit binary data in emails)